# Multiple outputs quantile regression

Tags: regression, threshold, quantiles, pmml

I am building a model to determine upper and lower thresholds for *multiple features* with respect to multiple others.  (Specifically, I want to see if certain pressure measurements in an HVAC system are within normal ranges with respect to ambient temperature and electric current draw.) I would ultimately like to save such a model to PMML, or some other kind of standard.

I have had success using the quantile L1 loss in [sklearn's GBT regressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html) as well as in [LightGBM's LGBM regressor](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1036) to find a *single percentile* for a *single pressure measurement*, and am able to use either [sklearn2pmml](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) or [Nyoka's new pmml library](https://github.com/nyoka-pmml/nyoka) to save such a model.

1. Is there a way of making either regressor work with *multiple outputs*?
2. Is there a way of making such a regressor work with *multiple percentiles*?
3. Is there a way to save such a pipeline to pmml or some other standard?

The first question is similar in nature to the one [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153853/regression-with-scikit-learn-with-multiple-outputs-svr-or-gbm-possible), but I suspect a complete solution may look a bit different because of the PMML/exporting concerns.